# Intellij Remote Debugging Tomcat

Tags: debugging, tomcat, remote-debugging, intellij-14

I am using intellij and tomcat to do debug. At this moment I am able to debug but when I change the code I do not see these changes and intellij ignores the changes, debug on old code.

I use the following software:

- IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2
- Tomcat 8.5

Configuration intelliJ

- Edit configurations
- add tomcat server - local

[image]

Configuration tomcat:

in the file service.bat

> --JvmOptions "-Xms3G;-Xmx4G;-Xmn512m;-XX:+UseCompressedOops;-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC;-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;JPDA_ADDRESS=8000;JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket;-D%ENDORSED_PROP%=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties;-Dedtftp.log.level=ERROR;-DaddRoleInfo=true;-Dftp_dandori_host=localhost;-Dftp_dandori_user=ftp_creactives;-Dftp_dandori_pwd=S0mMeR2O14;-DtestWS=test;-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=**62568**,suspend=n,server=y;-DwriteSAP=test;-DstopAutoGR=yes;-DstopLDAPUsers=yes;-Ddisable.new.upload=true;-Dh4c.config.path=%CATALINA_HOME%..\files\conf"
>   ^